# How to make the rows of a HTML table display one by one, with delay?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I want to make the rows of my HTML table display one by one with delay. I am using Flask

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table class="styled-table">
    <tr>
    {% for header in headings %}
        <th>{{ header }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {%for row in data_listed %}
        <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
            <td>{{ cell }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I tried to search on Internet but didn't find the answer

Comment: From my understanding, Flask is a server-side language, so all of the table rows would be created before the HTML is sent to the browser. You could add JavaScript/CSS to delay the display of the rows, but that sounds like a good way of making customers unhappy...

Comment: [Using CSS transition and class toggle to show/hide table rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55629239/215552) should get you started.

Comment: Can you tell me more? I don't know CSS/JS that much. Even with this topic I don't manage to do that. I'm new to coding lol

Comment: This site isn't geared toward tutorials or mentoring. It's about specific answers to specific programming-related questions (see the [tour] and [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

you can use setInterval to time the rows.  Just be sure to clearInterval when you're done

```js
let tds = document.querySelectorAll('td')
let cnt = tds.length


const myRowTimer = setInterval(displayRow, 1000);
let row = 1;

function displayRow(){
   tds[row].classList.toggle("none");
   row++
   if(row == cnt)clearInterval(myRowTimer);
}
```

```css
.none{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'>row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'>row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='none'>row 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello, firstly thanks for helping me.

I just copied your code and it works perfectly except the first row.

screenshot here: https://ibb.co/RbLj5w0
Do you know why?

Comment: the first row should display right away as there's no class='none' on it.  You would have to show me your code?  Does it work the way you want in the snippet?

Comment: it looks like you have class='none on the second td if the first row.  delete the class and it should work